# How to align an iframe horizontally (in the centre of the screen) with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm embedding a YouTube video inside an ***iframe***, which I put inside a div.
The problem I'm dealing with right now is that I can horizontally align (in the centre) the text but not the *iframe*.

This is the code I used to make this:

> HTML

```
<div id="box-logo">
    <img src="Content/Media/red_package.png" />
    <span>Quem somos?</span>

    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uz0d_oeRfaU?autoplay=1"
            frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#box-logo {
margin-top: 40px;
text-align: center;
}

#box-logo img {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#box-logo span {
    color: red;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#box-logo iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 895px;
    height: 435px;
}
```

I've been searching for multiple tips and I could't find one which could solve my problem.
I'd gladly hear your suggestions in order to try them out!

Thanks in advance,
Granvic

Comment: wrap these iframe in div and make that div in center.

Comment: try this `#box-logo iframe  {margin:0 auto;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the margin of your `#box-logo iframe` to `0 auto`.

This is because you have the element with the `display` property set to `block`, so it takes the entire line. As you set the `width` to determinate amount of `px` there is some free space in the line. Setting `margin: 0 auto` you are indicating that free space must divide equally to each side of the `div`.

In the case you have the `iframe` `display` property set to `inline` or `inline-block` this wouldn't work. To get the `div` centered, in that situation, you should apply `text-align: center` to `#box-logo`

Here you have a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g2s384L2/

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the iframe responsive by using this code

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */
 
.flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.flexible-container iframe,   
.flexible-container object,  
.flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uz0d_oeRfaU?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to update your css with

```
iframe {display:inline-block;}
span {display:block;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wpnjk2rf/

Answer (score -1):

you can set like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uz0d_oeRfaU?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 600px;height: 300px;
display: inline-block;"></iframe>
```